# Web2Py view can't see Lazy Virtual Field

Tags: python, html, web2py

I've declared a table and [virtual field](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/35/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#New-style-virtual-fields--experimental-) as follows in my model: (I've tried the two commented out declarations as well and they don't work)

```
scan_db.define_table('Shows',
    Field('Name', unique=True),
    Field('Logo', 'upload'),
    Field('Delim', default='$'),
    format= '%(Name)s')

#scan_db.Shows.src = Field.Virtual(lambda row : URL('download', args=row.Logo))
#scan_db.Shows.src = Field.Lazy(lambda row, alt=None : URL('download', args=row.Logo))
scan_db.Shows.src = Field.Lazy(lambda row, alt=None : URL('download', args=row.Logo if alt==None else alt))
```

In my controller, I've the following function and I've modified `download():` so it grabs from `scan_db` (`download()` is tested separately with displaying an image from `scan_db` and it works.)

```
def showlist():
    shows = scan_db(scan_db.Shows).select()
    return dict(shows=shows)
```

In my view, I have:

```
{{for rec in shows:}}
{{=rec.src()}}
```

I get the error: `<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'Row' object has no attribute 'Logo'`

If I change `{{=rec.src()}}` to `{{=rec}}` then it displays a list of these:

`<Row {'Name': 'PolarBear', 'Delim': '$', 'Logo': 'Shows.Logo.a1ef7016cfa89d1e.506f6c61722d437261702e706e67.png', 'id': 1L}>`

It looks like `Shows.src` is never getting added in my model. ... ???

---

The code in the view is not intended to display the actual image. I took that out to try and narrow down the actual problem. I'd originally intended the following line to use the image.

```
<Button type="button" src="{{=rec.src()}}" onclick='window.location="{{=URL('showscans', args=rec.id}}";'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `row.tablename.fieldname` syntax in your virtual/lazy field definitions. Also, it is best to include the name in the declaration:

```
scan_db.Shows.src = Field.Lazy('src',
    lambda row, alt=None : URL('download', args=row.Shows.Logo if alt==None else alt))
```

Comment: Totally forgot to mention I got the bad syntax from the docs. Where do I properly report or fix that? The example here: http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/35/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#New_style_virtual_fields_%28experimental%29 has `>>> db.item.total_price = Field.Lazy(lambda row, discount=0.0:        row.unit_price*row.quantity*(1.0-discount/100))`

Comment: Unfortunately, that version of the book sometimes comes up in search results. It is an incomplete Chinese translation that is a couple editions behind the current English version. You should instead use http://web2py.com/book, which shows the correct syntax for this case.

Comment: You didn't notice the first three chapters where in Chinese? :-(

Comment: Weird, just checked and apparently I have the right version printed. Somehow my bookmarked links almost all point to the wrong version because I've been jumping around in it but I managed to download the right version for printing.